# why is Snowbird browser faster than Windows Explorer..?

Tags: windows, explorer, dos

I was wondering how such performance can be achieved on windows as I noticed snowberd is even faster than DOS "dir" command, even in mapped network drives...?

Any idea what algo/technology are used to get such fast directory browsing...?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most proper way is using [Windows Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773177%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) stuff.

Maybe dir command is slow because of screen output overhead? When I do "dir >output.txt" I don't see any significant performance difference with file browsing software.

Comment: I have no idea what "Snowbird" is, but, as an experienced software developer, I know that screen output is very costly.